# Manipulando list<int> em c++

Tags: c++, ponteiro, lista

Minhas Classe

```
class Grafo{
int numeroVertice;
list<int> *arestas;

public:
Grafo(int vertices);
int addVertice(int quantidade);
void addAresta(int verticeOrigem, int verticeDestino);
void remAresta(int verticeOrigem, int verticeDestino);
void verificaAresta(int verticeOrigem, int verticeDestino);
int grauVertice(int vertice);
void percorreLista(int v);
bool existeLigacao(int origem, int destino);
};
```

Meu construtor:

```
Grafo::Grafo(int vertices){
 this->numeroVertice = vertices;
 arestas = new list<int>[vertices];
}
```

Meu problema:

```
int Grafo::addVertice(int quantidade){
arestas = new list<int>[vertices];
return this->numeroVertice = this->numeroVertice + quantidade;

}
```

Como fazer para quando esse método addVertice, aumente a quantidade de alocações para a minha lista 'arestas'?

Estava pensando em usar algo como:

```
  it=std::set_union (first, first+5, second, second+5, v.begin());
  v.resize(it-v.begin());
```

Só que estou usando ponteiro aí me perco, alguém de boa vontade aí?
O objetivo final é a lista que tem 5 alocações, poderia ser aumentada para 10 por exemplo.

Comment: Não seria apenas o caso de usar um [`push_back()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/push_back/)?

Comment: Acho que isto aqui **arestas = new list<int>[vertices];** está criando um array de listas, é isso mesmo que você quer ? Ou você queria criar uma lista com n vértices ? Neste caso acho que deveria ser **arestas = new list<int>(vertices);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que você está implementando um grafo através de uma lista de adjacências.
Minha sugestão é, em vez de usar alocação dinâmica para a lista, use um `std::vector`. E para a lista de arestas de cada vértice, também sugiro utilizar `std::vector` em vez de `std::list`. Ficaria algo assim, mais ou menos:

```
class Grafo {
    using ListaAdjacencias = std::vector<int>;
    std::vector<ListaAdjacencias> arestas;
}
```

Desta forma, você pode controlar o número de vértices pelo `size()` do `std::vector`. Toda a alocação e liberação de memória é abstraído e você pode se concentrar no problema real que você quer resolver.

Seu construtor ficaria mais simples:

```
Grafo::Grafo(int vertices) : arestas(vertices) {
}
```

Para adicionar um novo vértice basta adicionar um novo item à lista:

```
int addVertice() {
    arestas.push_back( {} ); 
    return arestas.size() - 1; //Retorna o índice do novo vértice;
}
```

Não é necessário definir previamente o número de arestas daquele vértice. Deixe que as classes de contêiner cuidem disso pra você. Para adicionar uma nova aresta bastaria:

```
void addAresta(int verticeOrigem, int verticeDestino) {
    arestas[verticeOrigem].push_back(verticeDestino);
}
```